# MFMailComposeViewController in Android?

Tags: android, email

is there something like MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone for Android, basicly Activity which handles email addresses and email creation etc. ? or all must be made from scratch by me?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about the `MFMailComposeViewController` from iPhone but I don know Intents of Android. You can use these to send input gathered from user and allow device installed email clients to handle it for you.

```
try{
    Intent emailIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"sample@email.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample Body");
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
//Theres no email client installed on users device.
}
```

You can use EditText android widgets to accept input from user. Use `EditText.getText()` to
do so.
You can also specify that you want to use default email client of the device by setting up intent with

```
emailIntent.setClassName(com.android.email, com.android.email.activity.MessageCompose);
```

This will launch default email clients compose window. Where use may choose to edit and send message.

Make sure you always **catch ActivityNotFound exception** since there might not be any available email clients installed and/or configured.